# Angular2 Resolve promise inside a subscription?

Tags: angular, promise, resolve, subscribe

Is there any way to get this pseudo code to work?

```
private letsSee(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.someService.someValue.subscribe((nextValue) => {
      resolve(nextValue);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this code (that is not pseudo at all) would not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: so I again tried it, there is no error but `this.letsSee().then(res => {console.log(res)});` does not output anything... even after I modified the above code to `resolve(true)`

Answer (score 1):

convert an Observable to Pormise :

```
private letsSee(): Promise<any> {
  return this.someService.someValue.toPromise();
}
```